# Are cookies compresssing with gzip encoding?

Tags: http, http-headers, gzip

Are http headers compresssing with gzip encoding together with request body when request header: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems no, because Accept-Encoding declares encoding in headers. So, cookies also are sending without gzip.  It could make redundant network loading, particularly when many asset files are on page.